# How to combine attributes from 2 objects that are not received upon initialization

Tags: python, object, concatenation, addition

This is my code. I would like to know how to combine the "_transactions" attributes from 2+ objects.

Could you please help me out?

```
class Account:

def __init__(self, owner, amount=0):
    self.owner = owner
    self.amount = amount
    self._transactions = []

def add_transaction(self, amount):
    if type(amount) != int:
        raise ValueError("please use int for amount")
    self._transactions.append(amount)

def __add__(self, other):
    name = f"{self.owner}&{other.owner}"
    starting_amount = self.amount + other.amount
    self._transactions += other._transactions
    return Account(name, starting_amount)

acc = Account('bob', 10)
acc2 = Account('john')
acc.add_transaction(20)
acc.add_transaction(-20)
acc.add_transaction(30)
acc2.add_transaction(10)
acc2.add_transaction(60)
acc3 = acc + acc2
print(acc3._transactions)
```

The output should be:

```
[20, -20, 30, 10, 60]
```

But instead is:

```
[]
```

Comment: `__add__` is not doing anything to make sure that the created object's `self._transactions` won't be empty, why would you expect that output?

Comment: @DeepSpace, sorry, I didn't write the whole code. I edited it. acc has _transactions = [20, -20, 30], and acc2 has _transactions = [10, 60]. I would like acc3 to combine both _transaction lists into [20, -20, 30, 10, 60]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the `__add__` function in order to sum the transactions; infact when you instatiate a new class, the `self._transactions` attribute is an empty list by default.

```
class Account:

  def __init__(self, owner: str, amount: int = 0, transactions: list = None):
      self.owner = owner
      self.amount = amount  
      self._transactions = [] if transactions is None else transactions
    
  def __add__(self, other):
      name = f"{self.owner}&{other.owner}"
      starting_amount = self.amount + other.amount
      transactions = self._transactions + other._transactions
      return Account(name, starting_amount, transactions)
    
  def add_transaction(self, amount):
      if type(amount) != int:
          raise ValueError("please use int for amount")
      self._transactions.append(amount)

acc = Account('bob', 10)
acc2 = Account('john')
acc.add_transaction(20)
acc.add_transaction(-20)
acc.add_transaction(30)
acc2.add_transaction(10)
acc2.add_transaction(60)
acc3 = acc + acc2
print(acc3._transactions)

>>> [20, -20, 30, 10, 60]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice way to do it. Here I found another way to do it without changing the init: https://pastebin.com/sAGu7kBM